# Find all function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=1$ & $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+2xy$.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity, functional-equations

Find all function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that : $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=1$ and for all reals $x,y$ : 
$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+2xy$$

I tried to solve it and I got the following  :

If $x=y=0$ we have $f(0)=0$

I wanted to use the limit but I couldn't :
$$\text{We know that :} f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+2xy$$
Thus :
$$f(x)=f(x+y)-f(y)-2xy$$
$$\therefore \frac{f(x+y)-f(y)-2xy}{x}=\frac{f(x+y)-f(y)}{x}-2y$$
I think that I need to substitute that $f(x+y)$ but I don't even know if this is true or no !

Comment: The argument you gave shows that $f$ is differentiable with $f'(y) = 1+2y$ for every $y.$ Thus, $f(y) = y^2 + y.$

Comment: Agreed @Will M.

Comment: Here is an alternative argument.  Let $g(x)=f(x)-x^2$.  Then $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$.  Therefore $g$ satisfies [Cauchy's FE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).  Since $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)}x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}x=1,$$ $g$ is continuous at $0$.  Therefore $g(x)=kx$ for some $k$.  Prove that $k=1$ so $g(x)=x$ and $f(x)=x+x^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will edit what you have done, the functional equation can be written as :
$$f(x+y)-f(y)=f(x)+2xy$$
Thus : $$\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^*\times \mathbb{R}: \ \ \ \frac{f(x+y)-f(y)}{x}=\frac{f(x)}{x}+2y$$
If $x\to 0$ then :
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(y)}{x}=1+2y$$
Thus $f$ is differentiable and $f'(y)=1+2y$, note that $f(0)=0$ .

Finally :
$$\int f'(y)\ dy=\int 1+2y \ dy=y+y^2+C$$
Therefore your function is :
$f(x)=x+x^2$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}= \left( \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{x} \right)-2y, \forall y\in  \mathbb{R}$$

Hence you have $f'(y)=2y+1,  \forall y \in \mathbb R$

$$\therefore f(x)=x^2+x+c , \forall x \in \mathbb R $$  where $c$ is a constant .

Now from the functional equation we can show that $c=0$

Comment: You missed something I think !

Comment: Yes I did . Now I think it's ok ! @Abcd23Mex

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the hint !

Comment: So should I remove the rest ?

Comment: No, why should you remove it ?